# Which Layer for Domain Events, EventHandlers, Dispatcher

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design, domain-events

I have been reading about **Domain Events** and have seen codes from Udi's implementation(http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/)
,Mike Hadlow (http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/separation-of-concerns-with-domain.html), Jimmy Bogard  and Jason Dentler's implementation.

All in all I like the idea of  events.

My questions is which layer should I add these components.

I am not going to use any BUS and **all events will be handled in Synchronous fashion**.

I guess the interface IDomainEvent , IEventHandler should go in **Project.Core** where rest of the interfaces are kept and accessed by all projects.

The Dispatcher (which is a static class) I believe should go into **Project.Infrastructure**.

I will create a new Project just for Handlers of domain events. lets say **Project.EventHandlers**.

I will use IoC (structuremap) to register all handlers.

The Events themselves as I see are based on Business Language and  for that reason I believe should go to **Project.Domain** where all Aggregates are implemented.

Let me know if this is the right way.

My other confusion is on project references. Should **Project.Domain** reference **Project.Infrastructure** so that it can use the static **Event Dispatcher**.

Should **Project.EventHandlers** reference **Project.Domain**  because It needs to know what events are there that can be handled.

I am planning to create a StructureMap Registry class in **Project.EventHandlers** that will be then BootStrapped in Global.asax.

If this has been talked before please point me to the link. I couldn't find one through Google Searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are these projects or namespaces? There's an ancient and ongoing debate about fine-grained verses coarse-grained project structure. I'm in the coarse-grained camp. An assembly is a unit of deployment, not a logical layer, and the structure you are describing is better achieved as namespaces in a single project.

Having said that, your organisation looks sensible. My only change would be to put interfaces alongside their implementations rather than in Project.Core.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I had the projects as different assembly and you have made me rethink some of these assemblies ( if not all) as namespaces, which I think will lead to simpler implementation. Said that, how can I achieve lose coupling if Interfaces are put alongside their implementation? By having them in a different assembly I was referencing core in MY MVC app as well as Services layer.